# Powershell xml script to extract value from <Property name="xx" value="yy"/>

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this xml file structure where the parent folder name is the job number.  Then inside the folder, there is a file with the same name as the folder with a .xml extension.

Using PowerShell, for each folder and xml file, I need to retrieve the `psModelled` value of the first occurrence of the `<Property name="ProcessStatusID" value="psModelled"/>` tag

I can't figure out how to get the property value.  Hoping someone can help me with that code.

If the value = 'psClosed', then I need to move the entire folder to a different archive folder, but I'll worry about that once I succeed in getting the property value.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DentalContainer version="2016-1">
  <Object name="MainObject" type="TDM_Container">
    <Object name="OrderList" type="TDM_List_Order">
      <List name="Items">
        <Object type="TDM_Item_Order">
          <Property name="IntOrderID" value="6862911"/>
          <Property name="TraySystemType" value="stNone"/>
        </Object>
      </List>
    </Object>
    <Object name="ModelJobList" type="TDM_List_ModelJob">
      <List name="Items">
        <Object type="TDM_Item_ModelJob">
          <Property name="ModelJobID" value="MJA98D88967006476CB010B2C41328F5A4"/>
          <Property name="OrderID" value="6862911"/>
        </Object>
      </List>
    </Object>
    <Object name="ModelElementList" type="TDM_List_ModelElement">
      <List name="Items">
        <Object type="TDM_Item_ModelElement">
          <Property name="ModelElementID" value="MEA4A179CFB6B74BC2A38373D720629ECE"/>
          <Property name="ProcessStatusID" value="psModelled"/>
          <Property name="ValidationResult" value="vrPassed"/>
        </Object>
      </List>
    </Object>
    <Object name="ElementList" type="TDM_List_Element">
      <List name="Items">
        <Object type="TDM_Item_Element">
          <Property name="ElementID" value="TEC89CECF82CAD4F54B3E26A56E40971FA"/>
          <Property name="CacheTypeClass" value="teAbutment"/>
        </Object>
      </List>
    </Object>
  </Object>
</DentalContainer>
```

Here is my code so far.  I know it is rookie code, but I am a PowerShell rookie.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell2 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        # // Store subfolder path in a variable
        $sFolderPath = $_.FullName
        $sFolderName = Split-Path $sFolderPath -Leaf

        if ($sFolderName -eq '6862911')
        {

          Get-ChildItem $sFolderPath | Where {$_.Name -like $sFolderName + '.xml'} | foreach{

            $sFilepath = $_.FullName

            'FilePath='+$sFilepath
            'length='+$sFilepath.Length

             [xml]$xml = Get-Content $sFilepath
             $sNode = $xml.selectNodes('//Property') | select Name

             $sNode+'-->sNode length='+$sNode.Length

             if ($sNode -eq 'ProcessStatusID')
             {
               'inside the loop'
             }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the current output

```
FilePath=C:\temp\pwrshell2\6862911\6862911.xml
length=37

name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
IntOrderID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
TraySystemType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ModelJobID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
OrderID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
ModelElementID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ProcessStatusID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ValidationResult                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ElementID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
CacheTypeClass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-->sNode length=
9
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should try something like this: `$xml.SelectNodes('//Property') | ?{$_.name -eq "ProcessStatusID"} | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty value`

Comment: Awesome, thanks n01d.  Perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Powershell code is pretty convoluted, let's clean that up first.

You have a directory, which contain sub-directories, which contain `*.xml` files. You are interested in working with those files.

`Get-ChildItem` makes this easy with wildcards:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell2\*\*.xml
```

Now you want to load the XML and select the *"value of the first occurrence of the `<Property name="ProcessStatusID" value="psModelled"/>` tag"*.

The XPath expression to select these elements would be `//Property[@name = 'ProcessStatusID']`.

Since we only want the first occurrence we can use [the `SelectSingleNode()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell2\*\*.xml | foreach {
    echo $_.FullName 

    [xml]$doc = Get-Content $_
    $ProcessStatusID = $doc.SelectSingleNode("//Property[@name = 'ProcessStatusID']")

    # never forget to check if there even is a match
    if ($ProcessStatusID) {
        echo "ProcessStatusID: $($ProcessStatusID.value)"

        if ($ProcessStatusID.value -eq "psClosed") {
            $_.Directory | Move-Item -Destination C:\ArchiveFolder
        }
    } else {
        echo "ProcessStatusID not found"
    }
}
```

Done.

Have a look at the [`FileInfo` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), because that's the type of object `Get-ChildItem` gives you here.

Comment: Tomalak, thanks for the code and the explanation. It helped alot.  Now, what is the best way to schedule this to run daily?

Comment: If it helped, instead of saying "thanks" in a comment, upvote it. Upvotes are the "nice" and "thanks" of this site. I'm sure you can figure out how to schedule a script on Windows, that's not rocket surgery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer based on n01d's help.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        # // Store subfolder path in a variable
        $sFolderPath = $_.FullName
        $sFolderName = Split-Path $sFolderPath -Leaf

          Get-ChildItem $sFolderPath | Where {$_.Name -like $sFolderName + '.xml'} | foreach{

            $sFilepath = $_.FullName

            'FilePath='+$sFilepath

             [xml]$xml2 = Get-Content $sFilepath
             $sValue = $xml2.SelectNodes('//Property') | ?{$_.name -eq "ProcessStatusID"} | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty value
             '$sValue='+$sValue

             if ($sValue -eq 'psClosed')
             {
               Move-Item $sFolderPath C:\temp\pwrshell3
             }
          }
    }
}
```